# How to make a Next.js route with /users/:id/verify/:token

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am trying to create a component that renders in a Next.js app at path /users/:id/verify/:token.

I understand how to create a route for /users/:id

But I cant seem to understand how to add another /verify/:token onto the end of that route and show something

currently I have my pages set up like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) You can use folders to catch all routes, like this.

[image]

then the route `/users/12/verify/99` would give you id=12 and token=99 in [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

Was it something like that you were after?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. So in the pages directory I create a file named users/[id]/verify/[token].js and it creates that folder structure you have there and whatever component I create in the [token].js file shows when I got to a route like localhost:3000/users/234890fh/verify/2398fhaaeh